# GDB crashes when calling function with non-const QString reference of temporary from other function

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

I'm trying to find a non-slow method to print `QString` values from within GDB. My approach is to define a function (to be used only from within GDB) that takes a non-const reference to a `QString`, converts it to non-Unicode string, and sends the result to standard output. But using it in the manner I desire to use it causes a crash as explained below.

Suppose I have the following functions defined:

```
void printQString(const QString & in)
{
  // The other option is to use GDB trickery as indicated by http://tinyurl.com/k6mfgxy but that is DOG SLOW:
  printf("%s\n",in.toLocal8Bit().data()); fflush(stdout);
}

void crunchOnIt(const QString & in)
{
   // ... Do something useful with "in" here ...
}

void someFunc()
{
  QFileInfo fileInfo("/tmp/flubberBouncesBest");
  fileInfo.makeAbsolute();
  if (fileInfo.isSymLink()) {
    crunchOnIt(fileInfo.symLinkTarget()); // <-- You are right here in GDB.
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Suppose you run the above from within GDB and are on the line indicated by "You are right here in GDB".

Now from within GDB you want to inspect the return value of `fileInfo.symLinkTarget()` *before* calling the crunchOnIt function. When I try the obvious, I get what looks to be a crash:

```
(gdb) call printQString(fileInfo.symLinkTarget())

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff059ba4b in gconv () from /usr/lib64/gconv/UTF-16.so
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(printQString(QString const&)) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

If, however, if GDB steps into crunchOnIt, and I call printQstring with the "in" parameter, it works just fine.

Having to edit the program to add a temporary, e.g.,:

```
void someFunc()
{
  QFileInfo fileInfo("/tmp/flubberBouncesBest");
  fileInfo.makeAbsolute();
  if (fileInfo.isSymLink()) {
    QString tmp = fileInfo.symLinkTarget(); // <-- No I don't want to have to recompile the program to insert this temporary!
    crunchOnIt(tmp);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and recompile defeats the purpose of the `printQstring` function, because recompiling a large C++ program just to add temporaries is a significant waste of development time.

Is this a GDB bug whereby it is not keeping track of the temporary created by the `fileInfo.symLinkTarget()` expression that needs to be fed to the `printQString` function?

What alternatives do I have other than inserting the `tmp`-orary above?

Comment: GDB doesn't work with temporaries well. It uses its own memory to store them, not target program memory. As a consequence, a temporary cannot be passed to a function by reference, because its address cannot be taken (the object lives in an entirely different address space). My version of GDB does not crash, it says "Attempt to take address of value not located in memory", albeit with a simpler example, not involving Qt. It says the same thing when trying to use something like `& (5)`.  It's a limitation of GDB. I'm afraid not much can be done here.

Comment: @n.m.: That makes sense to me now, and that is what I was afraid of.

Comment: Can you work around the problem by changing your function to accept `QString` instead of `const QString &`? Just a guess.

Comment: @sashoalm: I tried passing by value as you stated, and it also crashes.  The problem is the temporary is in a different address space. I'll just have to live with this for now I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug open in gdb's bugzilla about this problem.

Meanwhile, it's generally better to use gdb's pretty-printing facility rather than helper methods in your program.  The pretty-printer approach works in many situations that a helper method cannot: they automatically work in backtraces, in "info locals", and if you are examining core files.

Pretty-printers are written in Python.  They're generally quite simple to write.  There are probably already printers written for QString somewhere... aha: http://nikosams.blogspot.com/2009/10/gdb-qt-pretty-printers.html